# android material searchview shows text and icon as grey

Tags: android, searchview

The material searchview from github(https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) that I am using in the applications shows both text color and close icon as grey eventhough I set it as white.Screenshots are also included.

activity_main.xml:

```
<com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MaterialSearchView"/>
```

styles.xml:

```
 <style name="MaterialSearchView">
    <item name="searchBackIcon">@drawable/left</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="searchBackground">@color/searchbackground</item>
    <item name="searchCloseIcon">@drawable/close</item>
    <item name="searchSuggestionIcon">@drawable/marker2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/searchtextcolor</item>

</style>
```

colors.xml:

```
<color name="searchbackground">#7986CB</color>
    <color name="searchtextcolor">#ffffff</color>
```

Screenshot:[image]